# What is the difference between setequal(a,b) and identical(a,b) in R?

Tags: r

If I set `a` and `b` like below,

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(1,2,100)
```

what is the difference between `setequal(a,b)` and `identical(a,b)` in R ?

I mean, what is the difference with definition fundamentally?

Comment: They both have helpfiles - `?setequal` & `?identical`. You can even see what the code of setequal() is by entering `setequal` at the command prompt. The most basic example showing the difference is probably something like `setequal(c("a","b"),c("a","b","b"))` vs `identical(c("a","b"),c("a","b","b"))`

Answer (score 5):

Difference comes in when

- there are duplicated values;
- there are different ordering.

Consider two examples

```
a <- rep(1:3, 1:3)
b <- 1:3
setequal(a, b)  # TRUE
identical(a, b)  # FALSE

a <- 1:3
b <- 3:1
setequal(a, b)  # TRUE
identical(a, b)  # FALSE
```