# I want to identify columns names that are filled with zeroes and NAs in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with about 111 columns, few of the columns are entirely filled with zeros and NAs.I want to programmatically identify the column names that have only zeroes and NAs,

I used the below to find columns that entirely have NAs

```
a<-data[,((colSums(is.na(data)) == nrow(data))==T)]
names(a)
```

Now I want to find column names that are filled with a mixture of Zeroes and NAs ,how can I do that ?

Comment: Please post samples of variables in your post too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a job for `setequal`:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=1:4, b=c(0,NA,1,NA), c=c(0,NA,0,NA), d=c(0,NaN,0,NaN), e=NA, f=0)
names(dat)[sapply(dat, setequal, c(0,NA))]
#[1] "c"
```

`setequal` essentially compares the unique values of two vectors to make sure they are totally overlapping. See here: [What is the difference between setequal(a,b) and identical(a,b) in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777625/what-is-the-difference-between-setequala-b-and-identicala-b-in-r) for more info.

Comment: Nice option with `setequal`.  I didn't realize the clause about only NA and 0.

Answer (score 4):

As you don't provide a minimal representative dataset, we first generate some sample data

```
set.seed(2017);
df <- setNames(data.frame(
    rep(0, 10),
    runif(10),
    runif(10),
    rep(NA, 10),
    runif(10),
    sample(c(NA, 0), 10, replace = T)), letters[1:6])
df;
#   a          b           c  d          e  f
#1  0 0.92424261 0.674331481 NA 0.63411352  0
#2  0 0.53717641 0.002020766 NA 0.37986744 NA
#3  0 0.46919565 0.025093514 NA 0.94207403 NA
#4  0 0.28862618 0.432077786 NA 0.75499369 NA
#5  0 0.77008816 0.499391912 NA 0.22761184  0
#6  0 0.77276871 0.388681932 NA 0.91466603  0
#7  0 0.03932234 0.395375316 NA 0.62044504 NA
#8  0 0.43490560 0.715707325 NA 0.31910458 NA
#9  0 0.47216639 0.940999879 NA 0.07628881 NA
#10 0 0.27383312 0.827229161 NA 0.26083932  0
```

Then we can use `all` with `is.na` and `x == 0` to identify null/`NA` columns

```
names(df)[sapply(df, function(x) all(is.na(x) | x == 0))]
#[1] "a" "d" "f"
```

Comment: Just as an aside, `is.na(NaN)` would be a fringe case that will break this.

Comment: @thelatemail True, but perhaps `NaN` should actually get flagged?

Comment: Very possibly, OP seems rather quiet on feedback so I guess we'll wait and see!

Answer (score 1):

Using `setequal` as the thelatemail did is the clearest, as well as distinguishing between `NaN` and `NA`s. If you really need it to be fast though, you may want to consider:

```r
only_zeroes_and_NAs <- function(v) {
  is.numeric(v) &&
    anyNA(v) &&
    suppressWarnings({
      # min(v, na.rm = TRUE) will emit a 
      # warning if all are NA, which we can ignore
      min(v, na.rm = TRUE) == 0 &&
        max(v, na.rm = TRUE) == 0
    })
}

only_zeroes_and_NAs_or_NaN <- function(v) {
  is.numeric(v) &&
    anyNA(v) &&
    suppressWarnings({
      # min(v, na.rm = TRUE) will emit a 
      # warning if all are NA, which we can ignore
      min(v, na.rm = TRUE) == 0 &&
        max(v, na.rm = TRUE) == 0
    }) &&
    !any(is.nan(v))
}

set.seed(6)
N = 10e6
dat <- data.frame(a=sample(1:4, size = N, replace = TRUE),
                  b=sample(c(0,NA,1,NA), size = N, replace = TRUE),
                  c=sample(c(0,NA,0,NA), size = N, replace = TRUE),
                  d=sample(c(0,NaN,0,NaN), size = N, replace = TRUE),
                  e=NA, f=0, g = NA_real_)

bench::mark(me = names(dat)[sapply(dat, only_zeroes_and_NAs)],
            me_nan = names(dat)[sapply(dat, only_zeroes_and_NAs_or_NaN)],
            setequal = names(dat)[sapply(dat, setequal, c(0, NA))], 
            check = FALSE,
            filter_gc = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 10
#>   expression      min     mean   median      max `itr/sec` mem_alloc  n_gc
#>   <chr>      <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt> <dbl>
#> 1 me          331.3ms  331.5ms  331.5ms  331.7ms     3.02   140.16KB     0
#> 2 me_nan      453.2ms  467.5ms  467.5ms  481.8ms     2.14    76.34MB     1
#> 3 setequal       2.1s     2.1s     2.1s     2.1s     0.477    1.69GB     6
#> # ... with 2 more variables: n_itr <int>, total_time <bch:tm>
```

<sup>Created on 2018-06-28 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

One can try using `dplyr::select_if` to get the names of columns having only `0` or `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% select_if(funs(all(is.na(na_if(.,0))))) %>% names()
#[1] "a" "d" "f"
```

**Data:** Sample data taken from `@MauritsEvers`