# checking if two sets are equal where order doesn't matter in R?

Tags: r

so I am trying to write a simulation to test the probability of a certain topping selection coming up when picking 4 toppings on a pizza. (total topping selection = 7)

```
toppings = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),4,replace = FALSE)
certainSelection = c(1,2,3,4)

toppingsSorted = sort(toppings)

certainSelectionCounter = ifelse(certainSelection == toppingsSorted, certainSelectionCounter + 1, certainSelectionCounter)
```

I have the exact probability done on paper, and the above attempt is the closest i can get to it, without the sorting its worse, which tells me that this is making order matter. is there any built in functions in R that will check if 2 sets are equal where order doesn't matter?

Comment: `?base::setequal` See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777625/what-is-the-difference-between-setequala-b-and-identicala-b-in-r).

Comment: probably should have included, setequals gives me an even worse answer.

Comment: Why worse? What is the expected result? `1/choose(7, 4)` gives `0.02857` and a simulation with `setequal` gives `0.0286`, doesn't seem much different.

Comment: okay, actually I think I was making a mistake, I had it running the simulation 200 times, so i was getting the 0.0286. so I assume that is only checking the set once.

now I just need to find a way to get set equals into a for loop i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replicate` to run the simulations. From the documentation of `?replicate`, my emphasis:

> `replicate` is a wrapper for the common use of sapply for repeated evaluation of an expression (which will usually involve **random number generation**).

In the code below I set the pseudo-RNG seed in order to make the results reproducible.

```r
# compare the draws with this vector
certainSelection <- c(1,2,3,4)

# number of simulations, 10K
R <- 1e5

set.seed(2022)
res <- replicate(R, {
  toppings <- sample(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),4,replace = FALSE)
  setequal(certainSelection, toppings)
})
mean(res)
#> [1] 0.0286

1/choose(7, 4)
#> [1] 0.02857143
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>